# Why does my Pi 3 Model B with HAT DAC run fine on a 4V Lithium battery?

Tags: pi-3, power, battery

Everything I have read about the Raspberry Pi 3, model B says that it will not run reliably on anything below 4.6vdc. I have a Pi 3 and I am running it at around 4V DC with a single 18650 lithium battery. It boots up just fine on the Volumio 2 OS and it sounds wonderful. Can anyone explain why this is so?

I am not running any peripherals other than the Allo Boss HAT DAC. I know that the lithium battery has tons of headroom as far as amperage goes. I read this section on StackExchange which might suggest that only the HDMI port requires 5V DC:

> Power In from the μUSB connector goes through a polyfuse and an ideal
>   diode to provide 5V which is the 5V rail on the expansion header and
>   provides all power to the Pi including the following:
>
> Power in: a dual step-down converter (PAM2306) which provide 3V3 and
>   1V8 via a MOSFET to 5V_CORE and a Step-Down Converter (RT8088A) which
>   generates the VDD_CORE (nominal 1.2V). This was performed by the SOC
>   in the original Pi. voltage monitor chip (APX803) Power Switch
>   (RT9741) which produces H5V for HDMI

The Richtek RT8088A and RT9741 listed above both have an input voltage range of 2.7vdc to 5.5vdc so that's good.

Any opinions?

Comment: Lithium-Ion batteries experience voltages that fall over time as they are discharged. It may be 4.2 fully charged, but it is 3.7 nominal. I would recommend 2 is series and then use a cheap buck converter to get a stable 5volt supply as the battery voltage decreases over use.

Answer (score 1):

No one has said "Raspberry Pi … will not run on reliably on anything below 4.6vdc"; in fact the Pi itself will run until the voltage falls below the drop out voltage of the regulator. It should work reliably down to 4.2V, and I have done so in testing.

Actual components vary, what works on one Pi may not on another. I once worked with a major telecommunications manufacturer, which used 80286 processors to perform most tasks - but they **individually tested** each chip to select those which could be pushed beyond normal safe parameters.

The regulators are **step-down converters**; they will work on lower voltages **BUT** will **NOT** boost the voltage, and regulation will drop off as the input voltage falls.

The USB and HDMI use 5V, and may not work, again this depends on the external devices; many do not need power or work at low voltages.

I think a single Li battery is marginal, as at maximum it too low, and will drop with time.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) for detail, although you seem to have quoted from this.

You can run your car without oil for quite a while, but I would't recommend it!

Buy one of the cheap boost regulators which produce 5V from a LI battery.